# NGINX Redirect match location

Tags: laravel, nginx

I have a site who has a lot of routes (Laravel 5.7)

A couple of that routes are

```
"/insurance-travel-landing"  
"/insurance-travel-anual"
```

I need to point a WordPress installation at

```
"/insurance-travel"
```

I did with a NGINX location, but I have this problem:

When I write `"/insurance-travel"` in URL works Ok but when I wrote `/insurance-travel-landing` or `/insurance-travel-anual` I receive a 404 error of WordPress.

I tried do the location with exact match ("location = /insurance-travel")
but I have a problem with php location.

My Nginx Config (works insurance-travel, but the others not work)

```
location = /insurance-travel {
             alias /var/www/html/landing-travel;
             index index.php;
             if (!-e $request_filename) { rewrite   /insurance-travel/index.php last; }
                    location ~ \.php$ {
                    if (!-f $request_filename) { return 404; }
                    fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.1-fpm.sock;

                    include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
                    fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME $request_filename;
              }


    }
```

My config when I put = in location

```
location = /insurance-travel {
             alias /var/www/html/landing-travel;
             index index.php;
             if (!-e $request_filename) { rewrite   /insurance-travel/index.php last; }
                    location ~ \.php$ {
                    if (!-f $request_filename) { return 404; }
                    fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.1-fpm.sock;

                    include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
                    fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME $request_filename;
              }


    }
```

Nginx tell me this

```
nginx: [emerg] location "\.php$" cannot be inside the exact location "/insurance-travel".
```

How can I fix this?

Thanks!

Edit:

Server block

```
server {
server_name xx.xx.xx;
listen 443 ssl http2;

ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/xx/fullchain.pem;
ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/xx/privkey.pem;
ssl_trusted_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/xx/fullchain.pem;
include /etc/nginx/snippets/ssl.conf;

root "/var/www/html/xx/current/public";
index index.php index.html;
location / { 
     try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
}
location  /insurance-travel{
             alias /var/www/html/landing-travel;
             index index.php;
             if (!-e $request_filename) { rewrite   /insurance-travel/index.php last; }
             location ~ \.php$ {
                if (!-f $request_filename) { return 404; }
                fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.1-fpm.sock;

                include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
                fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME $request_filename;
          }

    }
sendfile off;

    client_max_body_size 100m;

    location ~ \.php$ {
           fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
           fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.1-fpm.sock;
           fastcgi_index index.php;
           include fastcgi_params;
           fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
           fastcgi_intercept_errors off;
           fastcgi_buffer_size 16k;
           fastcgi_buffers 4 16k;
           fastcgi_connect_timeout 300;
       fastcgi_send_timeout 300;
               fastcgi_read_timeout 300;
    }

 }
```

Comment: You cannot have nested location directive. Move .php location to root level

Comment: Where are your other locations place? below the `location = /insurance-travel` or upper than that?

Comment: `location = /insurance-travel` is an *exact* match. I think you want to remove `=`?

Comment: @num8er I tried to do that, but i can't figure it out how. When i access to insurance-travel , nginx return a 404 error

Comment: @MahdiJedari The others locations aren't defined  in nginx. I have a main site and  a couple of redirections inside who point to another directory in the same server.

Comment: @TravisBritz I tried to remove = and i have the same problem (insurance-travel is shown, but the others routes aren't 404 error). The other routes aren't defined in 
they are called from laravel route.

Comment: You need to show the complete `server` block - the question make no sense as it stands.

Comment: @RichardSmith I just edited my question. Thanks

Comment: I am guessing that the bottom `location ~ \.php$` block is to run Laravel. You need to use `location  ^~ /insurance-travel` so that your nested `location ~ \.php$` block can run WordPress.

Comment: @RichardSmith I tried, and wordpress run ok when i config location with this ^~. So the route `insurance-travel` work, but the other routes in laravel named `insurance-travel-anual` stop working (i think is because two url's share same name).

Comment: Ah I see. You could you use `location ^~ /insurance-travel/` to avoid ambiguity. You can add `location = /insurance-travel { rewrite ^ /insurance-travel/ last; }` to handle the edge condition.

Comment: @RichardSmith I tried, but doesn't work. Check this (is real site) i have a https://development.heymondo.es/seguro-de-viaje (who is wordpress landing) but also i have https://development.heymondo.es/seguro-de-viaje-temporal (who is handled by laravel). If i put nginx with your configuration, only work the landing wordpress.

Comment: Sorry, you need to add a trailing `/` to the `alias` value too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you want `/insurance-travel` to access WordPress, but `/insurance-travel-xxx` to continue to be processed by Laravel.

You can setup a location so that any URI beginning with `/insurance-travel/` is handled by WordPress and add an explicit rule the single URI `/insurance-travel`.

For example:

```
location = /insurance-travel {
    rewrite ^ /insurance-travel/ last;
}
location ^~ /insurance-travel/ {
    alias /var/www/html/landing-travel/;
    index index.php;
    if (!-e $request_filename) { rewrite ^ /insurance-travel/index.php last; }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        if (!-f $request_filename) { return 404; }
        fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.1-fpm.sock;

        include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME $request_filename;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Richard. The last configuration work as expected!. Again, thanks a lot !